# Javascript setTimeout Function constant looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with this animation looping over and over again. I looked through and could not find where the function for this is? Could you help me find where this is and how to fix it? I just want it to play once, when the site is launched and then stay. It is the .hero-logo (logo image).

```
      <!-- Begin Animation -->
    <script>$(function() {
  // Bind events and initialize plugin
  $('.hero-logo')**strong text**
    .on('pixellate-exploded', function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).pixellate('in');
  }, 500);
})
.on('pixellate-imploded', function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).pixellate('out');
  }, 500);
})
.pixellate()
});

var pluginName = 'pixellate',
defaults = {
 // Grid divisions
columns: 20,
rows: 20,

// Duration of explosion animation
duration: 1500,

// Direction of explosion animation ('out', 'in', or 'none')
direction: 'out',

// Resize pixels during animation
scale: true,

// Coordinates representing the source of the explosion force
//(e.g. [-1, 1] makes the explodey bits go up and to the right)
explosionOrigin: [0, 0]
  };

function Plugin(el, options) {
  this.$el = $(el);
  this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
  this._defaults = defaults;
  this._name = pluginName;

  this.init();
};



Plugin.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    if (!this.$el.find('.pixellate-pixel').length) {
      var $img = this.$el.find('img:first-child'),
        img = new Image();

      this.$el
        .data('pixellate-image', $img.attr('src'))
        .addClass('pixellate-lock');
      $img.css('visibility', 'hidden');

      $(img).one('load', $.proxy(this.createPixels, this));

     img.src = this.$el.data('pixellate-image');
      if (img.complete) $(img).trigger('load');
   } else {
      this.stylePixels();
    }
  },

  createPixels: function() {
    this.$el.append(new Array((this.options.rows * this.options.columns) +       1)    .join('<span class="pixellate-pixel"></span>'));

    this.stylePixels(true);
  },

  stylePixels: function(initializeStyles) {
    var self = this,
      w = this.$el.width(),
  h = this.$el.height(),
  columns = this.options.columns,
  rows = this.options.rows,
  $pixels = this.$el.find('.pixellate-pixel');

var styles = initializeStyles ? {
  'position': 'absolute',
  'width': (w / columns),
  'height': (h / rows),
  'background-image': 'url(' + this.$el.data('pixellate-image') + ')',
  'background-size': w,
  'backface-visibility': 'hidden'
} : {};

for (var idx = 0; idx < $pixels.length; idx++) {
  var pixelStyles = {};

  if (initializeStyles) {
    var x = (idx % columns) * styles.width,
      y = (Math.floor(idx / rows)) * styles.height;

    $.extend(pixelStyles, styles, {
      'left': x,
      'top': y,
      'background-position': (-x) + 'px ' + (-y) + 'px'
    });
  }

  if (self.options.direction == 'out') {
    var randX = (Math.random() * 300) - 150 - (self.options.explosionOrigin[0] * 150),
      randY = (Math.random() * 300) - 150 - (self.options.explosionOrigin[1] * 150);

    var transformString = 'translate(' + randX + 'px, ' + randY + 'px)';
    if (self.options.scale) {
      transformString += ' scale(' + (Math.random() * 1.5 + 0.5) + ')';
    }

    $.extend(pixelStyles, {
      'transform': transformString,
      'opacity': 0,
      'transition': self.options.duration + 'ms ease-out'
    });
  } else if (self.options.direction == 'in') {
    $.extend(pixelStyles, {
      'transform': 'none',
      'opacity': 1,
      'transition': self.options.duration + 'ms ease-in-out'
    });
  }

  $pixels.eq(idx).css(pixelStyles);
}

// Use rAF to ensure styles are set before class is modified
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  if (self.options.direction == 'out') {
    self.$el.removeClass('pixellate-lock');
  } else if (self.options.direction == 'in') {
    self.$el.one('pixellate-imploded', function() {
      self.$el.addClass('pixellate-lock');
    });
  }
});

// Fire plugin events after animation completes
// TODO: Use transition events when supported
setTimeout(function() {
  if (self.options.direction == 'out')
    self.$el.trigger('pixellate-exploded');
  else if (self.options.direction == 'in')
      self.$el.trigger('pixellate-imploded');
    }, this.options.duration);
  }
};

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
      $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
    } else if (typeof options === 'string') {
      $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName).options.direction = options;
      $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName).init();
    }
  });
};

// requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and   Tino    Zijdel
```

// MIT license
        var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
      window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] ||            window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
        }

```
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
  window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
    var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
    callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      },
      timeToCall);
    lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
    return id;
  };

if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
  window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
    clearTimeout(id);
  };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to start the animation over again after the elapsed time of the previous animation:

```
          // Fire plugin events after animation completes
          // TODO: Use transition events when supported
          setTimeout(function () {
              if (self.options.direction == 'out')
                  self.$el.trigger('pixellate-exploded');
              else if (self.options.direction == 'in')
                  self.$el.trigger('pixellate-imploded');
          }, this.options.duration);
```

FYI, I was unable to follow your code as posted because of improper indentation.  I had to paste it into http://jsbeautifier.org/ in order to be able to follow the code.

Comment: thank you! do you know how I can change that to have it only run once? and sorry about the format, I am not really familiar with JS, hence my dilemma.

Comment: @B-ridge - It looks to me like you can just remove that block of code.

Comment: thanks, when I remove that the animation stops working :/